# Installing rEFIt once Boot Camp is working

Tags: windows-7, mac, boot-camp, refit

I have a Mac OS X - Windows 7 setup working with Boot Camp. Is it safe to install rEFIt? Will it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've installed it and it recognized both partitions just fine and everything seems to be working correctly.